# Drupal: cannot unset js file and use new js in theme directory

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to copy a js file in my theme folder instead of hacking the module. This is my code:

```
 /*update js files */
  $scripts = drupal_add_js();

  unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/imagefield_crop/imagefield_crop.js']);
  $scripts['module']['sites/all/themes/zen/zen/js/imagefield_crop.js'] = array('preprocess' => 1, 'cache' => 1);

  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
```

IT works for lightbox2 but it doesn't work for imagefield_crop.js

I've cleaned all Drupal caches and browser cache but my browser continues to load the original js in the module directory.

thanks

**Update**: This is the array $scripts

```
['module']

...

    [sites/all/modules/imagefield_crop/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.js] => Array
                (
                    [cache] => 1
                    [defer] => 
                    [preprocess] => 1
                )
```

Comment: Have you checked that the original imagefield_crop.js entry is really present in the $scripts array before unsetting it?

Comment: ok I see, it is not there. How is it loaded then ? I thought scripts contain all modules js files.

Comment: Yup, it should be there somewhere, but maybe it is not added to the 'header' scope, or it is not added as 'module' type. Try to fill $script (temporary) with `$scripts = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL, NULL);` to get the scripts for all scopes and types, and check if you find the entry somewhere in the returned array - this could give you a hint on where it is included.

Comment: BTW, if you start your comment replies with '@Henrik Opel', I get notified about them - that way you do not have to wait until I eventually check this question by myself (if I remember to do it at all ;)

Comment: @Henrik Opel. Actually it is in my scripts. (I was checking the front-end theme instead of the back-end.. my mistake). I can see the added javascript file from my theme but I'm not able to unset the original one.

Comment: Could it be the path ? When I print scripts this is what I see <script type="text/javascript" src="/astudio/sites/danydiop/sites/all/modules/imagefield_crop/imagefield_crop.js?d"></script>

Comment: Well, that should be the themed output of `drupal_get_js()`, but your unsetting logic uses the (yet) unthemed array returned by `drupal_add_js()` - how does the entry look in there?

Comment: @Henrik Opel (1) For "unsetting logic" do you mean the preprocessed scripts array ?  (2) Ive tried to use dprint_r in template.php to see the unthemed array but it doesn't work. Sorry I need some guide to debug properly.

Comment: I mean the '$scripts' array from your posted code sample, right after the call `$scripts = drupal_add_js();` (I assume that sample comes from your themes `hook_preprocess_page()` function - right?).

Comment: @Henrik Opel : yes, that's the function. But my question in the comment before was how to inspect that array. If I use dprint_r I cannot see the results printed on the screen because it's not in page.php template file.

Comment: Try `var_dump($script); exit();` in your preprocess function (this should just output the variable and stop further script execution).

Comment: @Henrik Opel : finally i've printed it. I've updated my question, to show you. I really don't get why this line is not working then.   unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/imagefield_crop/imagefield_crop.js']);

Comment: The other script is added correctly but I cannot remove the old one.

Comment: Unless you posted the wrong snippet in your update, you are simply mixing up two different files - as it would not fit properly into a comment, I posted this as an answer below. (We can try to refine it there, if it still does not address your problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the updated question after the discussion in the comments, it seems like you are mixing up the involved js files. Imagefield_crop adds *two* different ones:

1. `jquery.Jcrop.js`, which is an imported library file providing the crop functionality in general (in context of jquery) - normally, you should not have a reason to replace this.
2. 'imagefield_crop.js', which is the one providing the 'bridging' to allow the above library to work properly in the Drupal context - my understanding was that you wanted to replace this one.

Both are needed for the functionality to work. Your posted code would only replace the second one, and unless you accidentally posted the wrong code snippet in your question update, it seems to work.

If you wanted to replace both (or only the first one), you'd need to extend/adjust your unsetting logic to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is the possible solutions it might help though I've never done this before

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter().
 * Based on the jquery_update module.
 *
 * Make this page preprocess function runs *last*,
 * so that a theme can't call drupal_get_js().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['page'])) {
    // See if our preprocess function is loaded, if so remove it.
    if ($key = array_search('MYMODULE_preprocess_page', 
      $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'])) {
      unset($theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][$key]);
    }
    // Now add it on at the end of the array so that it runs last.
    $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][] = 'MYMODULE_preprocess_page';
  } 
}

/**
 * Implementation of moduleName_preprocess_hook().
 * Based on the jquery_update module functions.  *
 * Strips out JS and CSS for a path.
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables, $arg = 'my_page', $delta=0) {

  // I needed a one hit wonder. Can be altered to use function arguments
  // to increase it's flexibility.
  if(arg($delta) == $arg) {
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    $css = drupal_add_css();
    // Only do this for pages that have JavaScript on them.
    if (!empty($variables['scripts'])) {
      $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_menu');
      unset($scripts['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.js']);
      $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
    }
    // Similar process for CSS but there are 2 Css realted variables.
    //  $variables['css'] and $variables['styles'] are both used.
    if (!empty($variables['css'])) {
      $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_menu');
      unset($css['all']['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.css']);
      unset($css['all']['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.color.css']);
      $variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
    }
  }
}
```

http://www.mediacurrent.com/blogs/remove-or-replace-jscss-page

Comment: +1 - this is basically what the OP tries to do from within his themes template.php, but with the additional step of ensuring that the preprocess_page callback used for the manipulation is definitely the last to be called. If the problems with his approach turn out to be related to the execution order, this might be the proper solution.

Comment: However, I doubt that the execution order is the culprit here - if it where, his own additions to the $scripts variable wouldn't make it to the page.tpl.php, as they would be overwritten by the changes from the later preprocess function.

Comment: By the way I don't see the reasons to override css/js includes provided by some modules or theme specific files, otherwise it seems to me it is better to provide your own custom extension.

Comment: Also, is it possible to make up with CCK?

Comment: @sultan: I agree that in general it is be better to extend instead of overriding existing js/css files, but depending on the nature and scope of the changes needed, sometimes it is a lot easier to simply replace what is there (if the 'extension' gets to convoluted to be easy to understand, simply replacing one file with another can be easier to maintain)

Comment: @sultan: I do not understand what you mean by 'make up with CCK' - could you rephrase that?

Comment: @Henrik Opel I meant by 'make up with CCK' any way to achieve @Patrick's goal using CKK